# Why does Stack Overflow not support personal messages?

Tags: discussion

I already have a new curios moment. Why doesn't Stack Overflow support personal messages from user to user?

- Is there a fear of stalking or spamming each other?
- Or maybe that question aren't resolved in normal Stack Overflow questions?

Does a really good reason exist, or am I totally incapable to find the function to "chat" directly to somebody else?

Comment: I can't imagine a deeper circle of hell

Comment: _'I totaly incapable to find the function to "chat" directly'_ There are some public chatrooms, where you can meet _certain people_ sometimes.

Comment: but you cant' directly chat to someone else

Comment: related [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/245167) and [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/245167)

Comment: You can talk directly to another in a chatroom

Answer (score 38):

Imagine the following scenario:

1. Person answers question
2. Question asker tries solution
3. Solution fails
4. Asker messages answerer
5. Answer and asker solve question within messages without updating the question.
6. Person stumbles across question tomorrow, tries broken solution, never resolves problem, gives up career and becomes a burger flipper.

So, while my example may be a little extreme, the entire point of SO is to store a repository of questions and answers. Personal messages would be used by either help vampires to hound people into giving them solutions, or would be used to solve the problem outside of the original question, which makes the entire point of SO redundant.

<sub>Just imagine Jon Skeet's day if help vampires could send personal messages.</sub>

Comment: I was contemplating the same question on the toilet (where i do all my clever thinking) now i feel stupid.

Comment: "Gives up career, becomes a burger flipper" *great* :D Besides that I fear that this could lead to kind of support overflow where the answerer/commentor becomes overwhelmed with further questions. Even though this might produce more intersting questions...

Comment: +1 for answer in general, but if I could I'd give it +2 for the "Jon Skeet/help vampire" comment.

Comment: "gives up career and becomes a burger flipper" ... lol ok now that's just stretching it

Comment: Jon Skeet lists his e-mail address on his profile, so help vampires totally *can* send him personal messages

Answer (score 5):

One of the best features of this site is not only to help the person who asks the answer, but to 'automatically' help future users having similar problems. By directly contacting each other, solutions, helps, comments etc. will only be known to the original asker, and not all future users.
It would really downgrade the usefullnes of this site.